# how to GET info from API in my html form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the same code that works with the geoip look up apiu but wont work for the asl look up. please help whats wrokng with this code why wont it work?

```
     <h3>Ip address ASL info</h3>
     <script>
      $(function() {
      $('#Search').on('submit', function() {
      event.preventDefault();    
      var url = 'https://api.hackertarget.com/aslookup/?q=1.1.1.1';
      var data = $('#Search').serialize();
      $.ajax(url + '?q' + data).then(function(data) {
      $('.output').text(data);

        });
          });
       });
       </script>
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <form method="get" id="Search">
         <input type="hidden" name="sites" value="" />
          <input type="text" name="q" placeholder="INFO" aria-label="Search" />
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
               </form>

                <div class="output"></div>
```

Comment: Try logging the data after your ajax function. console.log and also let's see the error on your console if any

Comment: anyone have a better api for port scanning? please include with code. This api is limited.